# How do I set up a mining pool server?

Tags: mining-pools, local

I want to setup a pool-server and a client image that gets work from that server.

I have access for an hour a day to about 40 computers that I can tftp boot, so once I learn how to make, configure, run, and connect to the server then I can make my image.

Comment: Why not simply let the clients join an existing pool? The turnout from a private pool will be just the same as when you let the clients mine individually.

Comment: Agree with @bananer: unless you want to do for educational purposes, it's pointless to host the pool yourself.

Comment: Similar question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/mining-pool-software-for-home-use

Comment: Hi David, voting to close this as a duplicate since it appears you're interested in setting up your own mining pool and there is already a question about that topic.  Also, as I'm sure you'll find once you dig into it, most of the time this isn't financially advantageous to do (at best it usually ends up as a way to very inefficiently take money from the person who pays the electric bill for those computers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run your private pool with a minimal amount of extra configuration, run bitcoind with -server and [some additional configuration](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin) for RPC commands. This would allow you to create a simple pool for your personal use.

However, [are you sure your mining endeavours would be profitable](http://tpbitcalc.appspot.com/)? You'd better check my calculator website that I linked right there. You might find it not worth your time to even set this thing up unless you have some really good GPUs in those machines.